# How do I get a counter with 0s before it?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create a simple animation with an array of images in Xcode.

But the array of images I got was named somePic Logo_1_-00000, where it increments... until somePic Logo_1_-00128.

```
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:COUNT];

for(int i=1; i<COUNT; i++)
            /*[myArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"./somePic Logo_1_%d%d.png", 4-(int)log(i),i]]];
```

I was trying to add 0s before the i depending on how big i is.

Basically, how do I get a counter, but with appended 0s before it?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08i", myInteger] pads an integer out to a width of 8 places, so 11 -> 00000011 and 7,523 becomes 00007523

Comment: full details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html

Comment: So, basically OP should use the format string @"%5d"

Comment: right, if we're going to leave nothing as an exercise I think the snippet is:
[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"./somePic Logo_1_%5d.png",i]

Comment: Hi, sorry but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong; I ran the code:
`for(int i=1; i<IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
printf("%s",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%5i.png", i]);`

and I got some weird output like <\343\207\214<\343\207\214<\343\207\214<\343\207\214<...

when I do `printf("%5i",i);` I'm getting:
    1    2     3
and so on, I see the padding, but there isn't any 0s.

Comment: you are mixing C code that deals with C strings (printf) with Objective-C code that creates NSString objects. Don't do that! try this: NSLog("%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%5i.png", i]);

Comment: Oh thank you! I tried `NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%5i.png",i]);`

I am getting (padding blank spaces) 0.png and so on

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. I searched around I didn't realize that the term for this was called padding.

I had to add an 0 before it. NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"% **0** 5i.png",i]);

Comment: edited my post, sorry I was sloppy... "%05i.png" is what we are looking for, the leading 0 says to pad with 0's to get to 5 digits.